# Returning multiplied property leading to recursion

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have the following case:

```
class MyClass (object):
    @property
    def _value(self):
        return self.value * 5

mapper(MyClass, myTableMetadata, properties = {
    "value": synonym("_value", map_column=False)
})
```

I'm completely aware why this is leading to recursion, but is there a way from the class to access the `self.value` property explicitly, not through the mapper?